# Mocking a dictionary upon FastAPI router instantiation

Tags: python, testing, mocking, fastapi, python-unittest

Attempting to write tests for an existing route and running into some roadblocks. I'm trying to mock a dictionary that is loaded when a router is instantiated, but it seems like the `@patch`'d versions I am supplying are loaded after the original dict is imported and computed upon.

Here is a simplified layout of files

`long_list.py`

```
big_dictionary = {'entry1': 'value1', 'entry2':'value2}
```

`main.py`

```
KeyName = Enum('KeyName', names=[key for key in big_dictionary])
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root(key_name: KeyName):
    return key_name
```

I would like to get a test case like this passing:

```
    @patch('main.big_dictionary', {'test_entry3': 'value3', 'test_entry4': 'value4'})
    def test_root(self):
        client = TestClient(app)
        response = client.get('/', params={key_name: "TEST_ENTRY3"})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response.json(), "TEST_ENTRY3")
```

currently, it is failing and saying that `TEST_ENTRY3` is not a valid enum value.

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't be using globals (module level variables) at all. Wrap `my_dictionary` in a getter function and inject it into the method via a `Depends` argument to the route. In the tests, use [Overrides](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-dependencies/) to update the dependency resolution for the test case.

Comment: If you need further customization for the route definitions, consider making a helper method which will dynamically add the routes (rather than loading them during module load). This adds some boiler plate to the startup, but allows you to easily create different variants of the app without needing to do any patching.

Comment: From what I've read, Depends doesn't quite work for what this endpoint accomplishes. When it populates `my_dictionary`, it is actually creating enums that are used to call the route. I'll update question with this requirement.

Comment: I would look to create a helper: `def add_custom_enum_routes(app: FastAPI, data: dict) -> None:` that can mutate an app to add the desired behavior. This way you can dynamically create the routes.

Comment: Interesting. Where would you suggest adding that helper? If I were to add it to the route itself, I think I'd  be running into the same testing issue. Adding it at a more broad level seems inappropriate, as the pattern doesn't exist elsewhere

Comment: Why use an enum here at all rather than validating the key within the route method body?